# Adding data from top rather than bottom

Tags: google-sheets

I want to put together a spreadsheet to input all of my future credit card transactions. Obviously, this sheet can get long fast.

I would like to know if it's possible to dedicate a row at the top of the sheet specifically to inputting new data, and having it push that data to the row below it. I don't want to have to scroll all the way down to the bottom of the sheet or have to manually insert a new row for each new transaction at the top of the sheet.

Basically, in visual form, this is what I'm looking to do:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+
|       Date |      Payee |    Amount |
--------------------------------------
|            |            |           | <- This row is dedicated to inputting new data
--------------------------------------
| 01/01/2020 |  Company 1 |      $123 |
--------------------------------------
| 01/01/2020 |  Company 2 |       $96 |
--------------------------------------
| 01/01/2020 |  Company 3 |       $45 |
+------------+------------+-----------+
```

When I enter new data into the row, in this case let's say I made a payment of $50 to Company 2 on 02/01/2020, I would like it to push it to the row below, to clear up that row for another input:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+
|       Date |      Payee |    Amount |
--------------------------------------
|            |            |           | <- This clears up
--------------------------------------
| 02/01/2020 |  Company 2 |       $50 | <- And my data gets pushed here
--------------------------------------
| 01/01/2020 |  Company 1 |      $123 |
--------------------------------------
| 01/01/2020 |  Company 2 |       $96 |
--------------------------------------
| 01/01/2020 |  Company 3 |       $45 |
+------------+------------+-----------+
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Show what you have tried including sample data, what you found from this site, from the official resources for end-users, and why they don't meet your needs. Please [edit] your question to provide the requested details. Once you have done that it can be reviewed, reopened, and answered. If you need further help, please read first [Guides to ask a \[google-sheets\] question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4935/88163).

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable the compatible keyboard shortcuts (Help > Keyboard shortcuts)
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> to insert a row

Alternative: use Google Apps Script and a edit trigger

Reference

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets